# Calculation of sum of numbers to reach a certain point

Tags: r, excel, sum

I have different decimal numbers each day and want to know how many days do you need to reach 1 or higher than 1 when you start adding percentages from different days.

My data looks like this:

```
days    percentage
1   0.187207822
2   0.221165007
3   0.002773814
4   0
5   0
6   0.159115287
7   0
8   0
9   0
10  0.080871794
11  0.080299951
12  0.011975184
13  0
14  0.197308657
15  0.272780872
16  0.167274086
17  0.142972819
18  0.07437692
19  0
20  0
21  0
22  0.079398371
23  0.075284697
24  0
25  0
26  0.06247718
27  0
28  0
29  0.167250066
30  0.189849856
31  0.048080715
32  0
33  0.024319067
34  0.031437684
35  0.083643198
```

When you start different days, you will need different days to reach 1 or higher. I want to know how to do it in R or in Excel. Thank you!

Comment: What is the expected result from your data? Are you talking about reaching a cumulative value of 1 from any series of consecutive days? Or non-consecutive random days?

Comment: @thelatemail cumulative. I have 4000 rows so I need to find out a formula or a code in R for the calculation.

Comment: @Kangmin - you should use dput() to generate output for these questions. See answer below for correct format of data for posting.

Comment: @John it's easy enough to input the data if it is in the format as it is currently in the question.  `dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="<paste here>")`

Comment: @MatthewLundberg can't believe I am only finding this out now.

Answer (score 1):

Something like below perhaps, which works through the first day to the maximum day, finding how long it takes to reach a cumulative sum of `>=1`:

```
result <- sapply(
  dat$days,
  function(x) which(cumsum(dat$percentage[x:length(dat$percentage)]) >= 1)[1]
)

result
# [1] 15 14 15 14 13 12 12 11 10  9 12 12 11 10 15 16 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
#[24] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

As @MatthewLundberg below notes, the `result` vector gives how many days need to elapse from the start point until a cumulative sum of `>=1` is reached.

Comment: I believe that the first value of 15 means that the next value desired is 15 slots down the vector.  That is, the 16 right before the first NA.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the data:

```
dat = structure(list(days = 1:35, percentage = c(0.187207822, 0.221165007, 
0.002773814, 0, 0, 0.159115287, 0, 0, 0, 0.080871794, 0.080299951, 
0.011975184, 0, 0.197308657, 0.272780872, 0.167274086, 0.142972819, 
0.07437692, 0, 0, 0, 0.079398371, 0.075284697, 0, 0, 0.06247718, 
0, 0, 0.167250066, 0.189849856, 0.048080715, 0, 0.024319067, 
0.031437684, 0.083643198)), .Names = c("days", "percentage"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-35L))
```

Here is a function to work it out.

```
find_cumsum = function(df, day){for(i in nrow(df)){
    df = df[df$days >= day,]
    return(min(df$days[cumsum(df$percentage) >= 1]))
    }
}
find_cumsum(dat , 3)
```

This function takes the data.frame and the day you wish to start at. It returns the day at which you have achieved a cumulative sum of 1 or greater. For example if you start your run on day 3 (as shown) you will exceed cumulative percentage on day 17.